# Merge two string arrays excluding some values

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge

I have those two arrays:

```
var a = ['a123', 'a321', 'a444', 'b3132', 'a123'];
var b = ['b3132', 'a321', 'a444', 'a123', 'a123'];
```

And I want to merge them with a condition and the value is not already on the array, when character 'b' is on the string , ignore it and proceed to merge, so the result would be:

```
var ab = ['a123', 'a321', 'a444'];
```

I have it solved on a loop checking the array values one by one but I think there's much better solution.

Comment: Did you try something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An ES6 solution - use a [`Set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to get only unique items, [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), and then filter the array to remove items that include `b`. If `b` is always the 1st letter in the string use [`String.prototype.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) instead of [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
const a = ['a123', 'a321', 'a444', 'b3132', 'a123'];
const b = ['b3132', 'a321', 'a444', 'a123', 'a123'];

const result = [...new Set(a.concat(b))].filter((item) => !item.includes('b'));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Wow, looks very smart solution.

Comment: It's an ES6 solution, so it might not work for you if you need to support older browsers.

Comment: It's perfect then, the app I'm building don't need old browsers support :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `concat` and `filter` to do it simply without looping both arrays

```js
var a = ['a123', 'a321', 'a444', 'b3132', 'a123'];
var b = ['b3132', 'a321', 'a444', 'a123', 'a123'];
var c = a.concat(b);
var d = c.filter(function (item, index) {
   return c.indexOf(item) == index;
});

console.log(d);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter()` and `concat()` like this.

```js
var a = ['a123', 'a321', 'a444', 'b3132', 'a123'];
var b = ['b3132', 'a321', 'a444', 'a123', 'a123'];

var result = a.concat(b).filter(function(e) {
  if (!this[e] && e.indexOf('b') == -1) {
    return this[e] = true;
  }
}, {})

console.log(result)
```